# I got a problem with subprocess.call() python

Tags: python, subprocess

Good Day,

I made a script that help me to comparing md5 hash of apps if it's official or not. As you know when you go to App official website you will see an official md5 hash for app to compare it with other copies.

My problem is when I test my script always gave me `NOT OFFICIAL` even if md5 Hash are same.

Here is my code

```
import subprocess

Hash = str.strip(input())
print(Hash)

Dir = str.strip(input())
print(Dir)

output = subprocess.check_output("md5 " + Dir, shell=True)
print(output)

if Hash == output:
    print("OFFICIAL")

else:
    print("NOT OFFICIAL")
```

and the output is :

```
b'MD5 (/Users/username/Desktop/test.py) =
86ece1d78b65fdb40058a3514d90df9d\n' NOT OFFICIAL
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `decode()` to convert `output` from `bytes` to `str`. Further, you also need to `strip()` it since otherwise you will be comparing a string with a newline vs. one without it. Finally, you may need to parse the output to remove whatever the `md5` utility prints alongside the hash (if anything).

---

Note: instead of spawning a process, a better solution is to use the standard `hashlib` module, which will also make your script portable, simpler and faster.

Note 2: you should use other newer hashes if possible.

Comment: Also it contains some text at the front (the `MD5 (...) = ` stuff).

Comment: @Thomas I assumed OP printed that (with non-matching code), but it is indeed very likely. Added too.

Comment: @Barmar Very true, added!

Comment: How can I convert byte to str exactly in which line and how?